# YII2 - check user

Tags: php, yii2

Okay, so, i am trying to write an API, and for the login function, you send the `phone` and `password` and if they match with a record in the database, we send back the user object.

You send `phone` and `password` via `GET` request, and I know what that means security wise, so don't mention that in solution.

Here is code for the API controller

```
<?php
namespace api\modules\v1\controllers;

use yii\rest\Controller;
use yii\data\SqlDataProvider;
use yii\web\Response;
use yii;
use common\models\User;

class UserController extends ApiController{

const STATUS_DELETED = 0;
const STATUS_ACTIVE = 10;
public $phone;
public $password;
private $_user = false;
private $password_hash;

public function actionIndex(){
    if(isset($_GET['phone']) && isset($_GET['password']))
    {
        $this->phone = $_GET['phone'];
        $this->password = $_GET['password'];
        if(!is_null($this->getUser($this->phone)))
        {
            //if the user is there, we try and validate the password
            if (Yii::$app->getSecurity()->validatePassword($this->password, $this->_user->password_hash))
            {
                echo ("good password");
                return $this->_user;
            } else
            {
                echo('bad password');
            }
        }else
        {
            return['User Not Found, Please Check Your Credentials And Try Again'];
        }

    }
    else
    {
        if(!isset($_GET['phone']))
        {
          return array('Please provide your phone number');
        }
        if(!isset($_GET['password']))
        {
          return array('Please provide your password');
        }
    }
}


public function getUser($phone)
{
    if ($this->_user === false) {
        $this->_user = User::findOne(['phone' => $phone,'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE ]);
    }
    return $this->_user;
}




}
```

According to [this section of the documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-security.html#validatePassword%28%29-detail), the `validatePassword()` should work, but even when i send the right password, it doesn't work.

Comment: try var_dump($this->_user);

Comment: when you do that before this line `if(Yii::$app->getSecurity()->validatePassword` the user object is actually there, the problem is with the password validation.

Comment: Is that the user you want to login?

Comment: yes....that is the user i want to login

Comment: nothing wrong so only can `$this->password` or `$this->_user->password_hash` is wrong. You can manually check it. http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php